Airflow: Is Multilevel dynamic task mapping possible in Airflow?
I am using dynamic task mapping to create tasks dynamically in the runtime. I am trying to extend this to further levels. Here is a diagram depicting the ask

I have tried expanding a task group. But Airflow doesn't allow expansion of tasks inside and expanded group
I tried expanding chained expansion ( it triggers only one Mapped_task2 after mapped task1)
